# Using Spring Security with a Cognito token

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I've hit a wall in trying to protect my API routes in Spring-Boot. I'm trying to figure out where the SecurityFilterChain gets the claims it needs to authorize calls. I made a custom filter but I'm not sure what to do next.

```
public class CognitoFilter extends GenericFilter {
@Override
public void doFilter(
        ServletRequest request,
        ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    // Get the Authorization header to get cognito groups from it
    String authHeader = req.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (authHeader != null) {
        System.out.println(authHeader.replace("Bearer ", ""));
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

With this filter chain config:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    // disable basic authentication (username and PW)
    http.httpBasic().disable();

    // disable Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)
    // In general not required for stateless Rst APIs that use CRUD
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

    http.addFilterBefore(
            new CognitoFilter(),
            BasicAuthenticationFilter.class
        )
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizer ->
                authorizer
                    .requestMatchers("/api/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "PROVIDER")
        );

    return http.build();
  }
}
```

I'm having a really hard time understanding how to setup Spring security to read my cognito token and where/how to tell it which claims to look at. Haven't seen tutorials that explain how the claims are obtained and parsed.

Any help with this would help a ton!

Comment: Get a look at [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials), all work with Cognito